# where is rosmake built in the groovy build from source sequence

Tags: ros, installation, ros-groovy, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
I have followed the document "Installing on Ubuntu from source". I am building on a Raspberry PI using raspbain.
Fuerte builds and installs in this environment. I have been able to get to section 2.2.3 "Build the ROS Stack"
and then the problem occurs.
It appears that when building the catkin system the basic commands should be built but they are not.
```

Once you run `catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/groovy` then rosmake should be at `/opt/ros/groovy/bin/rosmake`. You should be able to run rosmake after sourcing /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash.

```
I have searched the tree from /opt/ros/groovy level and the only rosmake found is at catkin_ws/src/rosmake.
```

You search in /opt/ros/groovy and found it in your workspace? That doesn't make sense to me, you mean that the only place you can find it is in your workspace?

```
It appears either that the command has not been built or installed in the correct location.
Where in the build sequence does rosmake get created and installed.
```

rosmake is a python script, it exists in the source space at catkin_ws/src/rosmake/scripts/rosmake and in the install space at <install_prefix>/bin/rosmake after you build and install the workspace.

```
And is the correct location for the executable in /opt/ros/groovy/bin or in /usr/local/bin.
```

The location depends on your install prefix, it will be the first if you use /opt/ros/groovy.  It would only be the latter if you explicitly told it to install to /usr/local.

```
Question:
Is there a generic porting instructions available or is the best I am going to do is the above document?
```

Those instructions (other than resolving dependencies) are generic and your best bet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51388/where-is-rosmake-built-in-the-groovy-build-from-source-sequence/) by [bobt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3863/bobt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answers inline, copied from ros-users mailinglist.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0